# Is there a list of 3rd party Python 3 libraries?

Tags: python, reference, python-3.x

More and more libraries are being ported to Python 3, and I suspect the changes will happen more and more rapidly as time goes on. However, as a non-newbie to Python, there are quite a few 3rd party libraries I use (matplotlib, pygame, pyGTK, Tkinter, among others). I know I should just be able to go to their site(s) to find out if they support python3k yet, but I'm wondering: is there a site anywhere that already has some type of list of 3rd party modules that work in Py3k?

Thanks

Comment: Other than http://pypi.python.org?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On the side menu at [pypi.python.org](http://pypi.python.org) there is a link entitled "Python 3 packages":

http://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=533&show=all

Comment: Ah, exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately it doesn't show up on a Google search for 'Python 3 3rd party [packages|libraries]'.